# SQL Redshift query to select first x dates within each group

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

Suppose my table looks like the following

```
user_id   login_date
1   2019-03-13 00:00:00.000000
1   2019-04-07 00:00:00.000000
1   2018-10-19 00:00:00.000000
1   2018-11-12 00:00:00.000000
1   2018-04-11 00:00:00.000000
6   2018-11-18 00:00:00.000000
6   2018-07-07 00:00:00.000000
6   2019-09-04 00:00:00.000000
6   2018-07-31 00:00:00.000000
6   2019-10-20 00:00:00.000000
12  2018-12-17 00:00:00.000000
12  2018-07-06 00:00:00.000000
12  2018-04-21 00:00:00.000000
12  2019-07-28 00:00:00.000000
48  2018-12-01 00:00:00.000000
48  2019-11-11 00:00:00.000000
48  2019-03-10 00:00:00.000000
48  2018-10-13 00:00:00.000000
48  2019-02-21 00:00:00.000000
48  2018-01-04 00:00:00.000000
```

I would like to select the logins within first 2 days after the first login. In other words, first have to find the minimum login date per group, and then select the ones that are within 48 hours, or sort the logins within each group and select the ones within first 2 days.

here is the SQL to create a similar table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (user_id INT, login_date DATE NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO TEST ( user_id, login_date)
VALUES
(1,'20190901'),
(1,'20140719'),
(1,'20101118'),
(1,'20101119'),
(1,'20141118'),
(6,'20110818'),
(6,'20070119'),
(6,'20090419'),
(6,'20070118'),
(6,'20100219'),
(12,'20120718'),
(12,'20070618'),
(12,'20041218'),
(12,'20041219'),
(48,'20120118'),
(48,'20111119'),
(48,'20031019'),
(48,'20100318'),
(48,'20021119'),
(48,'20010418')
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use window function `first_value()` in a subquery to retrieve the earliest login date per group, and then compare it to each login date in the outer query:

```
select 
    id, 
    login
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        first_value(login) over(
            partition by id 
            order by login
            rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
        ) first_login
    from mytable t
) t
where login < first_login + interval '2 days'
```

Another option is to use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select *
from mytable t
where login < (
    select min(login) + interval '2 days'
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id
)
```

Comment: I had to add ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING as RedShift requires it ! I wonder if you happen know which one could be more efficient ?

Comment: @user702846: you are correct, the frame clause is needed here, since we need `order by`, as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html). I cannot tell which solution would be more efficient beforehand, you woud probably need to test them both against your real data and compare performance.